# Ember.js store filter method not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Back here again,

Seems like Ember.js store.filter method doesn't work on my project. I want to filter my conversations list depending on if its opened or closed.

Route :

```
App.ListRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(){
        return this.store.filter('list', { status : 'opened'}, function(){ return true;});
    },
});
```

Model :

```
App.List = DS.Model.extend({

    readStatus: DS.attr('string'),
    status: DS.attr('string'),
    timeAgoElement: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

Empty controller :

```
App.ListController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({


});
```

Call result : http://gyazo.com/c68887958a58c6a40de5b871091ca55e

Ember inspector : http://gyazo.com/45e81fb11a46f9fc818b37b2e38d4317

Generated json is fine : http://gyazo.com/a7066358c5e440a15397cc42849f1835

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: In case that answer doesn't work, the way you are currently calling it, you are telling ember data to make a call for list records with the query param `api/list?status=opened` and then you are saying I want to filter all of the records currently in the store by my func (which you always return true from, so you are choosing to show any and all `list` records in the store)

Comment: Problem solved. Forgot to specify status parameter in rails backend. Thank you.